# how can i create playlist for shockwave player in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i want to play multiple swf files in a single shockwaveflash object instance one after other as a playlist..

so how can i create a playlist for shockwaveobject...in vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to generate the playlist as an xml file which you could do in VB using [linq to xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) or the xmlwriter class.